# ¿Cómo guardar variables en un archivo PHP y reutilizarlas?

Tags: php

Debo hacer un archivo para almacenar variables y reutilizarlas en todas las paginas, algo parecido a $_SESSION, pero en un archivo.txt, que se puedan modificar, como si modificara una variable normalmente

```
file_put_contents($dir,str_replace($src, $mod,file_get_contents($dir)))
```

> $dir posee la dirección del archivo.
>
> $src posee la palabra a buscar.
>
> $mod el string que se reemplaza (en $src).

En mi fichero archivo.txt contiene:

```
variable = hola

variable2 = buenas
```

Intenté con esta sentencia pero para cambiarle el valor a variable2 mi $mod debe tener `variable2= adios` y mi $src debe tener `variable2= buenas`. Lo que quiero es algo que busque `"variable2="` y su siguiente palabra se modifique **"buenas"** por **"adios"** sin tener que hacer todo el proceso de arriba.

Comment: Esto que intentas hacer, es realmente necesario? Es decir, es un ejercicio que te piden realizar o lo intentas hacer en un proyecto productivo. Como método es muy muy muy poco aconsejable. Lo que puedes hacer, es guardar como texto un array en la línea 1 de ese fichero, la lees completa, modificas los valores dentro del array y luego sobrescribes la línea o directamente el archivo con el nuevo array. Repito, como método productivo no me parece adecuado.

Comment: *sin tener que hacer todo el proceso de arriba* ... tal como yo lo veo lo que ya tienes está bastante bien, pues cualquier otra cosa implicaría el uso de más lineas y funciones, y no es tanta molestia buscar la linea entera tipo "variable2= buenas" y sustituirla por la nueva, **a menos que no sepas el valor de variable2 previamente**, ante lo cual entonces vale, habría que buscar otra forma.

Comment: Por cierto, el hecho de guardarlas en un archivo txt podria dar problemas de seguridad si alguien intenta abrirlo escribiendo su nombre directamente en la url, pues accederian a el y verian esos datos. Casi es mejor guardarlos en un archivo PHP directamente, en plan `<?php $variable = "hola"; $variable2 = "buenas";` (en lineas distintas) pues aunque accedieran a el, no verian nada, y luego lo incluyes con include alli donde lo necesites y andando (como un archivo de configuracion habitual de php).

Comment: El comentario de @masterguru es exactamente lo que yo haría en caso que no necesite mantener el valor de esas variables en futuros inicios de sesión. Si necesitas almacenar el valor para utilizarlo a futuro, pues una tablita de MySql lo soluciona todo. Seguridad, agilidad, rendimiento, etc etc etc.

Comment: ¿Cuál será el ámbito de esas "variables"? ¿Para todas las sesiones? ¿Para cada usuario? ¿Para cierto(s) usuario(s)?.

Comment: Claro entiendo lo que dicen, mi punto es por ejemplo crear un archivo css con php, poder editarlo y que se mantenga, o incluso editar archivos json para ajax, desde php. No almacenaría ningún tipo de información importante